# SFTP to copy recent timestamped file from remote server to local server using WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I have 2 types of files generating everyday in the remote server (`salaryreport_2014925_5010.zip` and `runningreport_2014925_4223.zip`).

Can anyone help me in completing the code to get recent files from remote server and copy to local server.

Till now I can all copy files from remote to local server :

```
option batch on
option confirm off
lcd E:\Source
open sftp://abcd:4125_273@abc.com:22
cd source/reports
get "salaryreport_"*
get "runningreport_"*
close
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

See the WinSCP article [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

---

Since WinSCP 5.9, you can use the [`-latest`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#latest) switch to make this a very easy task:

```
get -latest "salaryreport_"*
get -latest "runningreport_"*
```

---

For earlier versions:

- You can either download the (two) most recent file(s). That's not trivial using WinSCP.
- Or download files with current date timestamp. That's easy, if you use the the [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

  ```
  get "salaryreport_%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%_*"
  get "runningreport_%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%_*"
  ```

Answer (score -2):

set up a robocopy scheduled task on the server you need to move from?

```
robocopy "\\remote\files" "\\local\files" /E /MOVE
```